# Cannot build asp.net website after svn checkout

Tags: asp.net, svn, ankhsvn

I am using **AnkhSVN 2.5** to set up version control on my ASP.NET website.

I have a ready project, I installed AnkhSVN and then I added my solution to Subversion. When doing so I pointed out the repository where the project will be stored.

My working copy directory and my repository are on the same PC.

Now, on the same PC, I checked out the project in the repository to another working directory. The checkout was successful and I got all my source files correctly. However when I tried to build my project I get this error. **I cannot build my project.**

**The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'**

I tried to add a reference but I cannot find the assembly Microsoft.AspNet in the add reference list. In any case Microsoft.AspNet should be available by default. Why would I have to reinclude it?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

Comment: Did it build properly before adding to SVN?

Comment: What is using the AspNet namespace?  Where in the code is the build failing?  Do you have any broken references for your ASP.NET project? Expand the references folder in solution explorer and take a look.  There may be a dependency on something outside of the folder you checked in or something in the svn exclude list, so it didn't get checked into svn and hence will be broken at the other path.

Comment: Hmm, Did you try clean build? And, all system (asp.net) related dlls are usually in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5" folder. Try to add the references from there.

Comment: Yes, @Dan is correct. Worth checking that too

Comment: Does your solution have "private" references - usually in a `packages` folder in the file system? One way to check is to read the `.(cs/vb)proj` file/s - this should help regardless. Hth...